# Temporal Variogram

Tags: r, r-sp, gstat, geostatistics

I would like to build a temporal variogram, without specifying spatial coordinates as I have only one gauge that I'm studing temporally. Here is a sample of my data:

```
> head(test)
        POSTE       DATE  RR6
4485 63113001 1358609040  0.0
4486 63113001 1358609400  0.2
4487 63113001 1358609760  0.0
4488 63113001 1358610120  0.0
4489 63113001 1358610480  0.0
4490 63113001 1358610840  0.0
```

the date is in POSIXct form, I have a measure RR6 (variable of interest) every 360 seconds or 6 minutes. How can I do that ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

One possible is to create a "spatial coordinates" equivalent to your dates. Set latitude to any constant value, then do a linear transform of your time to longitude. For that you have to set an arbitrary delta of time to a delta of longitude, for example a delta of time of 60 seconds to 0.001° longitude. Then you have your data with "spatial coordinates" equivalent to your time. Width that data you can compute a variogram as normal in gstat.